# Setting custom header view in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-headers

I am trying to add a custom view to the header of each of my UITableView's sections. I am using this delegate method to return the desired view. It is working partly as it causes the cell sections to be spread out as if there was a header there, however neither the text or UIButton actually appear. I know this method is being called as I places an NSLog in the method to see if it was. Am I making some kind of silly mistake, or is this not the right way of doing this?

```
 - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
        customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];


        UIButton *headerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        // add button to right corner of section

        return customView;
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
                headerLabel.text = @"Team Name";
                break;
            case 1:
                headerLabel.text = @"Captain";
                break;
            case 2:
                headerLabel.text = @"Wicket Keeper";
                break;
            case 3:
                headerLabel.text = @"Batting Order";
                headerButton.center = CGPointMake( 160.0, 22.0);
                headerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                headerButton.tag = section;
                [headerButton   addTarget:self action:@selector(enableCellReordering:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [customView addSubview:headerButton];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        [customView addSubview:headerLabel];
        return customView;
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` delegate method? This is required if you implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: why do you return `customView` twice?

Comment: And @SpaceDust that answers my question, it was a silly mistake!

Comment: @SpaceDust Good catch. That extraneous call to `return` just before the `switch` is the problem.

Comment: @simonthumper since I am the first one who catches your problem, I should get the approved answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `return` your `customview` twice , one before switch statement one after switch statement twice just need to remove `return customView;`  before `switch (section)`

Answer (score 2):

Found it, you `return customView;` before the `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks, you've got sharper eyes than me haha!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
     NSString *string =[list objectAtIndex:section];
    /* Section header is in 0th index... */
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:166/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; //your background color...
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, @user3836191. It's customary to provide explanation about the functionality of your code in order to make it easier for other people to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

What about the custom header  origin.x and origin.y ?
when I set them non-zero, but it's still next to the ledt edge.